# Coffeescript: unexpected then in a switch statement

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, coffeescript, switch-statement

I'm trying to use a simple switch statement but it doesn't compile. Here's the code:

```
tag = 0 
switch tag
    when 0 then
        alert "0"
    when 1 then 
        alert "1"
```

The coffeescript compiler complains about an "unexpected then" in the line after the switch statement. 
I changed the code to this:

```
switch tag
    when 0 then alert "0"
    when 1 then alert "1"
```

and it works fine.

But I need multiple statements on multiple lines in the then parts of the switch statement. Is that impossible ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just drop the `then` altogether. You only need it when you don't want to have a new indented block.

```
tag = 0 
switch tag
    when 0
        alert "0"
    when 1
        alert "1"
```

(`if` works that way, too)